# Collectstatic command on production server

Tags: django

When I set DEBUG=TRUE on my local server - everything is ok.

But I want run my application on production server, so I pushed my code up to the server. Then on the server I run **collectstatic** to copy all the static files into STATIC_ROOT, and I got this errors:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've either specified your path incorrectly for a Windows machine (I think you have to use forward slashes and not backslashes, as if it were a UNIX path?  I do not use Python on Windows so I am not certain) or else the path you specified simply does not exist.

Comment: It's true - path I specified was wrong. I fix it, I run collectatic to copy all the static files into STATIC_ROOT, it work's but the static files still doesn' work ...

Comment: What do you mean by "it works but the static files still don't work"?  Do you mean that they are being copied to the correct directory but are not being served by your web server?

Comment: Yes. They are not being served by my web server. Probably the reason is that I didn't point my web server at STATIC_ROOT (actually STATIC_ROOT='')